# bootstrap 4 dropdown hiding back of the position sticky div

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to implement accordion in my page. I have a **Bootstrap 4** card inside accordion. I want to make card-header sticky when the user starts scrolling. I have dropdown on card-header section. When I open the dropdown it hides behind next card header. what to solve this issue?

```
<html>
 <accordion>
   <dropdown>
   </dropdown>
 </accordion>
</html>
```

[my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vishalgwalani/qfm5xvgo/4/)

**problem looks like this**
[[image: this image shows my problem][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIkMX.png)

Comment: please put your code, where we can test any

Comment: please see my fiddle @ÁlvaroTouzón

Answer (score 1):

Its solve you are using class "sticky-top" wich add z-index to title at 1020 so always apairs next text over  dropdown.
[Review my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u3sc4wgb/) its remove at third ones.

```html
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->
<div class="accordion" role="tablist">
  <div class="card" ng-repeat="">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading-1" style="top:0;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myaccordion">
      <div class="dropdown mx-3">

        <div class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          mydropdown
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown-menu" style="min-width: 8rem;">

          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <div>1</div>
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <div>2</div>
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <div>3</div>
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <div>4</div>
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <div>5</div>
          </a>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="myaccordion" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" aria-labelledby="heading-1">
      <div class="card-body" style="background-color:white;z-index:0;">
        hello world
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card" ng-repeat="">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading-1" style="top:0;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myaccordion1">
      <div class="dropdown mx-3">

        <div class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          mydropdown
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown-menu" style="min-width: 8rem;">

          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <div>1</div>
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <div>2</div>
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <div>3</div>
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <div>4</div>
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <div>5</div>
          </a>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="myaccordion1" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" aria-labelledby="heading-1">
      <div class="card-body" style="background-color:white">
        hello world
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card" ng-repeat="">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading-1" style="top:0;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myaccordion2">
      <div class="dropdown mx-3">

        <div class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          mydropdown
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown-menu" style="min-width: 8rem;">

          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <div>1</div>
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <div>2</div>
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <div>3</div>
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <div>4</div>
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <div>5</div>
          </a>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="myaccordion2" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" aria-labelledby="heading-1">
      <div class="card-body" style="background-color:white">
        hello world
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card" ng-repeat="">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading-1" style="top:0;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myaccordion3">
      <div class="dropdown mx-3">

        <div class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          mydropdown
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown-menu" style="min-width: 8rem;">

          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <div>1</div>
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <div>2</div>
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <div>3</div>
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <div>4</div>
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <div>5</div>
          </a>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="myaccordion3" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" aria-labelledby="heading-1">
      <div class="card-body" style="background-color:white">
        hello world
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card" ng-repeat="">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading-1" style="top:0;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myaccordion4">
      <div class="dropdown mx-3">

        <div class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          mydropdown
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown-menu" style="min-width: 8rem;">

          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <div>1</div>
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <div>2</div>
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <div>3</div>
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <div>4</div>
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <div>5</div>
          </a>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="myaccordion4" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" aria-labelledby="heading-1">
      <div class="card-body" style="background-color:white">
        hello world
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card" ng-repeat="">
    <div class="card-header sticky-top" id="heading-1" style="top:0;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myaccordion5">
      <div class="dropdown mx-3">

        <div class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          mydropdown
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown-menu" style="min-width: 8rem;">

          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <div>1</div>
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <div>2</div>
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <div>3</div>
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <div>4</div>
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <div>5</div>
          </a>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="myaccordion5" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" aria-labelledby="heading-1">
      <div class="card-body" style="background-color:white">
        hello world
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It didn't solve my problem. I want to make card-header sticky that's why sticky-top is used. If you try to increase the z-index of dropdown-menu it won't work I don't know why

Comment: take a look at bootstrap doc before use class that start in coflicts between https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/